# Semantic-ui: Change card width?

Tags: html, css, web, semantic-ui

Is there a way to change the width (or overall size) of semantic-ui cards?

I tried to change the `@width` variable in 
`semantic/src/themes/default/views/card.variables`
from `290px` to something else, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

There's also the option to use `fluid` and have cards dynamically fill the width of their container.

Answer (score 1):

should use `min-width`, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using max-width property! It should work.

Comment: I tried setting `@max-width: 100px` in both `semantic/src/site/views/card.variables` and `semantic/src/themes/default/views/card.variables`, to no effect.

Comment: Try changing the width property to max-width

Comment: transform:scale(0.5,0.5); try this css out. This scales the width and height to half size.